XV6 - Do we need to reset SPP and set SPIE explicitly?
kernel/trap.c of xv6 implements usertrapret, which sets up the RISC-V control registers to prepare for a future trap from user space. It clears the SPP bit and sets the SPIE bit in the sstatus register(on line 115-116) in order to get back to user mode with interrupts enabled.
// set up the registers that trampoline.S's sret will use
// to get to user space.
  
// set S Previous Privilege mode to User.
unsigned long x = r_sstatus();
x &= ~SSTATUS_SPP; // clear SPP to 0 for user mode
x |= SSTATUS_SPIE; // enable interrupts in user mode
w_sstatus(x);

However, I don't see the necessity of these lines of code.

If no nested trap happens, since this function handles traps from user space(as its name suggests), the SPP bit should already be 0 and the SPIE bit should already be 1.
If there are nested traps, then according to RISC-V Instruction Set Manual, an SRET instruction had already set the SPP bit to 0 and SPIE bit to 1.

I have deleted these lines of code and played around with the xv6 system, and everything seems to work fine. But I assume that there must be a reason for these lines of code to be there.
Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.
